# How do you make html5 video play on screen tap?

Tags: html, video, touch, tablet

I have the following code:

```
<video controls poster="poster.jpg">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

On desktop it works fine, if i click the video in the middle with my mouse on all browsers it starts playing. If I click when it's playing it pauses.

On mobile when I tap the middle of the video with my finger the same thing happens, that's correct.

But on my Windows 10 tablet when I tap the middle of the video nothing happens. It only plays if I tap the tiny default play button on the bottom left. Is there a way to make it play on tap of the center of the video?

I tried adding:

```
 onclick="this.paused?this.play():this.pause();"
```

after the poster tag but it didn't work, probably because it's not a click but a tap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need a custom click handler for your `<video>` element, but a more elaborate one, as you will have to suppress the default behavior of various clients also.

```
function playPause(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
  if (myVideo.paused) myVideo.play();
  else myVideo.pause();
}
```

and the appropriate changes in HTML

```
<video id="video1" controls poster="poster.jpg" onclick="playPause()">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```